# Android Sinch service not supported special characters in CallId

Tags: android, sinch

I am using sinch calling service for app to app call it works fine whenever i use int and string as callId in onSinchServiceConnected() But if user name has special characters then call is not placed.

```
AppConstant.CALL_ID = mCallId = getIntent().getStringExtra(
            SinchService.CALL_ID);//Contain Special characters.

//And in onServiceConnected() use

    Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant get your question perfectly but i think that is solved like this.
You can done this by using encode and decode of mCallId.
while placeing call encode callId

```
public String Encode(String str) {
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return base64;
}
```

and Use call id as

```
Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().callUser(Encode(name));
```

and on Receive call

```
public String decode(String str) {
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String text = null;
    try {
        text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

and use it

```
String userEncoded = call.getRemoteUserId();
String decodedUserName = decode(userEncoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general guideline, when calling with Sinch, phone numbers should be specified according to the E.164 number formatting (`[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164][1]`) recommendation and should be prefixed with a ‘+’.

Reference : https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#calling